# Changing cell's background is moving collection view offset to 1st element

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have horizontal collection view with autosize cells. I'm new to RxSwift and can't figure out what's wrong with this code. Whenever I click on any element collection view is set to start point. Only one option that I came with is to save offset of collection view right before reload and then manually set collection view offset to previously saved but it seems like bad practice to me.

This is my Cell:

```
class FilterCell: UICollectionViewCell {

   @IBOutlet weak var filterIcon: UIImageView!
   @IBOutlet weak var filterText: UILabel!

   func updateView(_ isSelected: Bool) {
      contentView.backgroundColor = isSelected ? .blue : .white
   }

   func updateData(icon: UIImage?, text: String?) {
      filterIcon.image = icon ?? filterIcon.image
      filterText.text = text ?? filterText.text
   }
}
```

This is Cell Model

```
struct FilterCellModel {
    let id: Int
    let image: String
    let text: String
    var isSelected: Bool = false
}
```

In View Model I only have Array of Cell Models:

```
class LoginViewModel {

let usernameTextFieldPublishSubject = PublishSubject<String>()
let passwordTextFieldPublishSubject = PublishSubject<String>()

let filters = BehaviorRelay<[FilterCellModel]>(value: [
    FilterCellModel(id: 0, image: "filter-ic-1", text: "Extra filter"),
    FilterCellModel(id: 1, image: "filter-ic-1", text: "Different extra filter"),
    FilterCellModel(id: 2, image: "filter-ic-1", text: "Short filter"),
    FilterCellModel(id: 3, image: "filter-ic-1", text: "Lorem Ipsum"),
    FilterCellModel(id: 4, image: "filter-ic-1", text: "Lorem filter"),
    FilterCellModel(id: 5, image: "filter-ic-1", text: "Ipsum filter")
])
```

And this is how I display cells and update them with RxSwift

```
loginViewModel.filters.bind(to: filterCollectionView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "FilterCell", cellType: FilterCell.self)) { cv, item, cell in
        cell.updateData(icon: UIImage(named: item.image), text: item.text)
        cell.updateView(item.isSelected)
    }.disposed(by: bag)
    
    filterCollectionView.rx.itemSelected.subscribe(onNext: { index in
        var filters = self.loginViewModel.filters.value
        let isSelected = filters[index.item].isSelected
        filters[index.item].isSelected = !isSelected
        self.loginViewModel.filters.accept(filters)
    }).disposed(by: bag)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you emit a new value out of the `filters` Observable, the collection view will reload. Part of what this means is that it goes back to the beginning. So the way to fix this is to make it so that you don't emit a new value from `filters` when the user selects an item.

There are a number of ways to do this.

- The simplest would be to remove the `isSelected` parameter from the `FilterCellModel` type. Instead track what items are selected through some other means.
- Another option would be to use a custom DataSource that only reloads the items who's state has changed. Check out the RxDataSources library for ideas.